# A* heuristics for when no node coordinates are available

Tags: algorithm, search, a-star

Scenario:

> Suppose I have a large pseudorandom graph complete with edge weights, but without any coordinate information associated with the nodes. In addition,
>       there are N waypoints evenly distributed around the graph, containing
>       precomputed shortest path information from each waypoint to every other node.

Goal:

> Find the shortest path between a random source and target node.

From previous problems I've solved using A* and what papers I've read on the subject, heuristics often seem to rely on euclidian metrics for computing good distance approximation, e.g. a straight line.

My question is therefore: is there any ok heuristic that can help me solve the above scenario, or am I forced to rely on pure Dijkstra's algorithm (combined with the precomputed waypoint nodes)?

Any ideas or comments will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Thanks to all of you who helped out, utilizing the triangle inequality did the trick. The nearest waypoint computation is quite expensive so the average runtime compared to pure Dijkstra is considerably higher, but this is of really no importance at this point in time.

Here's an overview over the number of explored nodes (random source/target for each graph type):
[image: number of explored nodes vs. graph type]

The first graph type *(1)* consists of about **200 nodes** and **250 edges**, while the last graph type *(40)* consists of about **8000 nodes** and **10000 edges** (higher type means larger graph).

Comment: If you precomputed all shortest-path pairs already, why would you need to run a shortest-path algorithm?!

Comment: But what do you want to find? What is the goal of the scenario?

Comment: Also, you can use [any optimistic heuristic for A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Admissibility_and_optimality), not just heuristics based on metrics

Comment: Sorry about that, the goal is simply the shortest path between two randomly selected nodes.

Comment: I don't think the waypoints will help you, since you can't really construct an optimistic heuristic from them. But maybe some other algorithm than A* could work

Comment: I agree, in my current setup I minimize with regards to all the waypoints, but it is neither optimal nor any better than pure dijkstra.

Comment: @NiklasB.: They shorten the processing time, if you find that a path from the start to waypoint X, which takes N steps to waypoint Y, then to the destination is the shortest, you don't actually have to find the path between X and Y until _after_ you've validated that it's the shortest total path.  And when you do get around to calculating that subpath, you know immediately when you found the shortest route, and can cut longer paths sooner than would be otherwise.  Slightly.

Comment: @MooingDuck I don't understand your reasoning, but I have already been proven wrong by Timothy

Comment: @senbon Don't recompute the shortest path to nearest waypoint every time! Reuse information between iterations.

Comment: Yes, I'll be implementing some form of caching/memoization in my next build. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We want an optimistic heuristic for length of the shortest path from A to B.

Find the nearest waypoint to A. Call it W.

Then max { d(W,B) - d(W,A), 0 } is a lower bound on the length of the shortest path from A to B.

> **Proof:**
>
> By the triangle inequality we have d(W,B) ≤ d(W,A) + d(A,B).
>
> Thus d(A,B) ≥ d(W,B) - d(W,A).

You could apply this idea symmetrically as well to get a slightly better bound. That is, find the nearest waypoint WA to A and the nearest waypoint WB to B and then your lower bound is

max { d(WA,B) - d(WA,A), d(WB,A) - d(WB,B), 0 }

What is nice about this heuristic is that it clearly improves as the density of waypoints increases.

Comment: That sounds good, would be happy to hear whether this gives a decent speedup for OPs random graphs

Comment: @NiklasB. Working on the proof...one moment. :) I don't think it does. Geodesics *always* satisfy the triangle inequality by definition.

Comment: Hmm, nevermind what I said. I was thinking the wrong way round

Comment: I will be trying this out after a decent nights sleep :-). Thanks alot for the help guys.

Comment: The TE is actually the proof for this: d(W,B) <= d(W,A) + d(A,B), which implies d(A,B) >= d(W,B) - d(W,A)

Comment: @NiklasB. I had to make a phone call and when I got back you had proved it for me. :) Although it's one line, it isn't as blatantly easy as it looks.

Answer (score -1):

Your heuristic can be:

```
shortest path distance between source and closest waypoint +
shortest path distance from that waypoint to your target node
```

**EDIT**

As Niklas has pointed out, this heuristic is not admissible. Therefore, it cannot be used in A*. Please disregard.

Comment: No, because it is not optimistic this is not a valid heuristic.

Comment: @iccthedral It doesn't even work for the `x -> x` case. `d(x,x) = 0`, but `h(x,x) > 0`, unless x is a waypoint